# Why is LoadLibrary failing to load an opencv_world DLL built by vcpkg but not the prebuilt binary version?

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, dll, vcpkg

I am trying to DllImport a DLL into a Windows .Net/C# application that has a dependency on OpenCV. It is my own DLL; I build it from source and implicitly link to the OpenCV "world" DLL, where OpenCV is built into a single DLL including all of its dependencies. This works when I use the prebuilt binaries from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/4.8.1/).

However I need to build an x86 version of this application as well as x64, and OpenCV does not provide prebuilt binaries for x86. Instead of trying to build OpenCV from source myself I decided to try to get it as a vcpkg package. I executed the following vcpkg commands:

```
.\vcpkg.exe install opencv[world]:x86-windows
```

and

```
.\vcpkg.exe install opencv[world]:x64-windows
```

This does give me `opencv_world4.dll` and `opencv_world4d.dll` and associated `.lib` files but when I attempt to DllImport my DLL with the OpenCV dependency and `opencv_world4.dll` next to my DLL in the working directory, this version of the DLL fails to load with a "not found" exception. If I directly try to `LoadLibrary` this DLL it returns NULL and `GetLastError` returns 126.

I am wondering if this DLL from vcpkg has not really been built with all the dependencies statically linked in or if this is some issue with the runtime library switch, /MT vs /MD or whatever? Any help appreciated.

Edit: looking at this with Dependency Walker it is clear that the DLL that vcpkg built has dependencies on various DLLs

[image: dependency walker screenshot]

whereas the prebuilt DLL does not. My question thus reduces to *Is there a way to get vcpkg to make a real `opencv_world.dll`*. To be clear the vcpkg documentation on the `world` features states as follows:

> Feature Name: world Description: Compile to a single package support
> for opencv Build-Depends: [object Object]

Comment: ***all the dependencies statically linked*** It should not statically link dependencies by default. If there is a dependency of a package it will be dynamically linked.

Comment: i thought that is what [world] means though?

Comment: try `.\vcpkg.exe install opencv[world]:x64-windows-static`

Comment: wont that make a static library?

Comment: Yeah opencv[world]:x64-windows-static builds a static library only. I need a DLL with no dependencies like what you get from the precompiled binaries that OpenCV distributes. I think there is no way to get that from vcpkg.

Comment: It is possible with vcpkg but you need a custom triplet which sets everything to static linking except for opencv

Comment: Thanks, but it's easier to just build from source.

Comment: Have fun but vcpkg is basically building from source.